# StringBuilder Class in Java Example

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm learning java through Lynda.com.

For one example, I am not sure why a longer syntax is needed for the StringBuilder class on my pc, as compared to the example on the website.

I cannot import the java.lang.StringBuilder into the java class

Screenshot from lynda.com:

[image]

Screenshot from my pc:

[image]

Comment: Please paste your code into your question.

Comment: @tb08 i can't see the issue.

Comment: Classes in `java.lang` don't need to be imported.

Comment: Please do not have the code available as an image. Copying and pasting would be preferable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You named your class `StringBuilder` as well. The compiler doesn't know if it should use your `StringBuilder` class or the  `java.lang.StringBuilder` class.

Better rename your class. It's never a good idea to name your class the same as a Java class from the standard API. Especially classes from the `java.lang` package which get imported automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You have called class `StringBuilder` (in the lynda - "Main"), so full path to library `StringBuilder` class is needed.